# How to parse integer values from regex and sum in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column that contains complex string and I am trying to extract out values from this string column. Here is the temp table and values -

```
with temp as  (
    select 1 as event_id, ';t-Tew00;1;1.00;252=100.00,;SM-R190;1;1.00;252=200.00,;SM-G998B/DS;1;6347.00;252=300.00,;EF-PG99P;1;249.00;252=400.00' as event_list union all
    select 2 as event_id, ';asdI-Tww5300;1;1.00;252=99.00,,;EP-TA845;.252=49.00' as event_list union all
    select 3 as event_id, ';asdI-Tww5300;1;1.00;252=10.00,,;EP-TA845;,.252=20.00,:etw:1002:2020,'
)
select *
from temp
```

I want to extract out all the `double/int` values after the appearance of `252=` in the `event_list` column. For instance, in the first record, I would like to extract the values `100.00,200.00,300.00 and 400.00`

I would like to add a separate column in the output that will `add` all such values together. So the output column for first record would be 1000.00. Likewise, `99+49` for 2nd record and `10+20` for 3rd record.

If no such appearance of `252=` appears then output must be 0.

How can I achieve this in BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
select event_id, 
  (
    select ifnull(sum(cast(value as float64)), 0) 
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(event_list, r'252=(\d*.?\d*)')) value
  ) as total_252
from temp
```

if aplied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: thanks @Mikhail for the answer, it works even in cases where the pattern is not present. I was trying to make it work in those corner cases and I was running this query - ```select event_id, event_list, cast(ifnull(regexp_replace(extracted, "252=", ""),"0") as float64) as product_amount
from temp 
, unnest (REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(event_list, '252=[0-9.]+'))  as extracted``` but it did not work